# Clustering a billion items (or which clustering methods run in linear time?)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a billion feature vectors and I would like to put them into approximate clusters. Looking at the methods from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering for example it is not at all clear to me how their running time scales with the data size (except for Affinity Propagation  which is clearly too slow).

> What methods are suitable for clustering such a large data set?  I assume any method will have to run in O(n) time.

Comment: Roughly how many features are in your feature vectors?

Comment: "Large" depends on the resources available to you. I suggest you try timing classification of smaller subsets and decide whether you need to move to more complex/distributed machine learning.

Comment: @NBartley There are only 4 features, ignoring any interaction terms one could create.

Comment: @mdurant One problem I have is that it's hard to tell scaling from testing small cases. I have a single powerful 64 core PC available to me with lots of RAM.

Comment: So you need to measure peak RAM usage as a function or number of elements?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many practical factors that can affect the running time.  The algorithm itself, of course, will usually have a theoretical complexity measurement.  However, your data set distribution will have much to do with the convergence speed (as seen in the pictures), as will initial input ordering.  As you noted, hardware features play a large part, not the least of which is the way your configuration happens to serve the algorithm's underlying implementation.

Overall, what is the shape of your data set?  Those screen shots show the variety of even toy examples.

Comment: If they are dense, discretization could reduce the vector set to a much smaller number.

Comment: @mdurant The issue I would like to focus on for this question is running time.

Comment: @Prune True.  However am I right that some methods simply take quadratic time so you won't get anything at all from them?  My data is in 4d so I am not sure how to describe the shape.

Comment: Describing the shape is a qualitative exercise.  Do you know anything about the data's "natural" clustering?  Does it tend toward hyperspheres (4-D clusters), or "cigars" (long, skinny ellipsoid-ish things), or planes, or a lot of little clumps of 500 to 1,000 points?  Does the data come in concentric spheres that you want to differentiate?

These considerations can focus the algorithm you need.  If there is a natural, visual separation between clusters, then many of the organic algorithms will converge far faster than their theoretical complexity would suggest.  How *nice* is your data?

Comment: I have been using [Kmeans][1]，O(K*n) Hadoop implementation is recommend if single machine memory is not able to hold all the data.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: Are you working for NSA?

Comment: @webdeb :)  Hard to imagine how anyone would have a billion feature  vectors?

Answer (score 4):

The K-means complexity sounds reasonable for your data (only 4 components). The tricky part is the initialization and the choice of number of clusters. You can try different random initialization but this can be time consuming. An alternative is to sub-sample your data and run a more expensive clustering algorithm like Affinity Propagation. Then use the solution as init for k-means and run it with all your data.

Answer (score 4):

For a billion feature vectors I'd be dubious of using K-means on its own.  I'm sure you could do it, but it would take a long time and would thusly be difficult to debug.  I recommend using [Canopy Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopy_clustering_algorithm) first *then* applying K-means to reduce the complexity and computations. These sub-clusters could then be reduced further with a Map Reduce implementation to solve even faster.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thank you!

Comment: @eleanora Have you tried k-means on a small subset of the data (1 million or 100 thousand features)?  If you're able to cluster a random sample of the data into only a few clusters then regular k-means may suit your needs.